# Copy properties from selector to another selector in Less

Tags: css, less

I'm new to Less. I know about variables, the basics of mixins and nested definitions.

I have a selector

```
.my-parent .my-child { color: red; }
```

and another selector

```
.foo .bar { color: green; }
```

I know every class is a mixin in Less by default, so I can do this

```
.foo .bar { .my-parent() }
```

however when I do this

```
.foo .bar { .my-child() }
```

my compiler complains because `.my-child` doesn't exist because it's *part* of another selector.

Can I create a new mixin that will copy all the properties from 1 whole selector to another?

Comment: `.my-parent` works as a [namespace](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-namespaces-accessors) there. So you need to use `.foo .bar {.my-parent > .my-child()}` or simply `.foo .bar {.my-parent.my-child}`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max, please add your comments as an answer